Getting CORS Error for only DELETE Request (Have no issues with PUT, POST and GET) DRF and React project
I have been facing this following error whenever I make the request from my react.js frontend. I am using django DRF on backend and nginx as reverse proxy. Both are deployed in gcp cloud run as different services. Meaning frontend and backend are in different origins, that prompted me to enable the CORS policy. I am fairly new to both of the technologies.
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend-service/api/employee/' from origin 'https://frontend-service' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
The weird part is, it's throwing the above error but the item is getting deleted in the database.
My views.py,
@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE'])
def handle_crud_operations(request, SerializerClass):
    if not SerializerClass:
        return Response({'message': 'Invalid serializer specified'}, 
                      status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# GET method to retrieve all objects of the specified model
    if request.method == 'GET':
        model_objects = SerializerClass.Meta.model.objects.all()
        serializer = SerializerClass(model_objects, many=True)
        return Response({'message': 'Successfully retrieved data', 'data': 
                         serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

# POST method to create a new object
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = SerializerClass(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': f'{SerializerClass.Meta.model.__name__} created 
            successfully', 'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# PUT method to update an object (full update)
    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        obj = get_object_or_404(SerializerClass.Meta.model, pk=request.data.get('id'))
        serializer = SerializerClass(obj, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': f'{SerializerClass.Meta.model.__name__} updated successfully', 'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# PATCH method to partially update an object
    elif request.method == 'PATCH':
        obj = get_object_or_404(SerializerClass.Meta.model, pk=request.data.get('id'))
        serializer = SerializerClass(obj, data=request.data, partial=True)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response({'message': f'{SerializerClass.Meta.model.__name__} updated successfully', 'data': serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# DELETE method to delete an object
    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        obj = get_object_or_404(SerializerClass.Meta.model, pk=request.data.get('id'))
        obj.delete()
        return Response({'message': f'{SerializerClass.Meta.model.__name__} deleted successfully'}, status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    return Response({'message': 'Invalid request method'}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)

@api_view(['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']   
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def employee_operations(request):
   return handle_crud_operations(request._request, EmployeeDataSerializer)

nignx file backend,
# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
   server unix:/djangoprj.sock; # for a file socket
}

server {
   # the port your site will be served on
   listen      8000;

   # the domain name it will serve for
   server_name https://backend-service; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
   charset     utf-8;

   # set gzip compression
   gzip on;
   gzip_vary on;
   gzip_proxied any;
   gzip_http_version 1.1;
   gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;

   # max upload size
   client_max_body_size 5M;   # adjust to taste

   # Django media
   location /static {
      alias /code/djangoprj/static;
   }

   # Finally, send all the rest to the Django server.
   location /api/ {
      uwsgi_pass  django;
      include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
      proxy_read_timeout 300;
      proxy_connect_timeout 300;
      proxy_send_timeout 300;
      send_timeout 300;

      # Handle CORS
      if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://frontend-service' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token' always;
          add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
          return 204;
      }

      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://frontend-service' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT, PATCH' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-CSRF-Token' always;
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
   }
}

My Frontend DELETE Request,
export function deleteEmployee(employeeId) {
  return axios.delete(`${backendUrl}/`, {
    data: { id: employeeId },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Token ${token}`,
    }
  })
  .then(response => response.data);
}

settings.py
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "djangoprj_web",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "corsheaders",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "djangoprj.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "djangoprj.wsgi.application"

# CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
#     "https://frontend-service-master-madmgxgaha-de.a.run.app",
# ]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    'DELETE',
    'GET',
    'OPTIONS',
    'PATCH',
    'POST',
    'PUT',
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    'accept',
    'accept-encoding',
    'authorization',
    'content-type',
    'dnt',
    'origin',
    'user-agent',
    'x-csrftoken',
    'x-requested-with',
]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

Any help would be appreciated. Please let me know if anything else needed.
